# Numpy xor-reduce an array

Tags: numpy, vectorization, xor

How to xor all elements of a boolean numpy array using vectorized methods: 
i.e., `a_1 xor a_2 xor ... xor a_n`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would prefer using the xor ufunc I think, which is `bitwise_xor` (or `logical_xor`):

```
np.bitwise_xor.reduce(a)
```

or:

```
np.logical_xor.reduce(a)
```

One advantage is, you don't get bogus stuff for floats.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably most efficient to just use `sum`:

```
np.sum(arr) % 2
```

Comment: Why would sum (plus-reduce) be more efficient than xor-reduce? They are both reduction, likely performed with the same code in the backend.