# XORing all values of a (2d) numpy array together

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, xor

If I have a 2d numpy array like (the data is not necessarily sequential but for example)

```
[[0. 1. 2. 3.]
 [4. 5. 6. 7.]
 [8. 9. 10. 11.]]
```

how can I compute 0^1^2^3^4^5^6^7^8^9^10?

I think I could flatten it and then use np.vectorize() but I was wondering if it was possible with numpy operations directly? From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14850140/numpy-xor-reduce-an-array) I tried `np.bitwise_xor.reduce(a)` but it says `TypeError: No loop matching the specified signature and casting was found for ufunc bitwise_xor`

Comment: I'm not a numpy expert but I would imagine the values for an XOR operation must not just be integers but also must have some kind of integer type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your arrays to some integer type

```
np.bitwise_xor.reduce(np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0]).astype(np.int32))
```

-> 0